# Unable to send mail with EmailJS

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-static mb-4">
          <label>First name</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="eg. Jason" aria-label="First Name..." type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 ps-2">
        <div class="input-group input-group-static mb-4">
          <label>Last name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="eg. Smith" aria-label="Last Name...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="input-group input-group-static">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="abc@.com">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-static mt-4">
      <label>Your message</label>
      <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-8">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn bg-gradient-info mt-3">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<!-- EmailSJ -->
<script src="https://cdn.emailjs.com/sdk/2.3.2/email.min.js"></script>
<script>
  (function () {
    // Add your EmailJS user ID here
    const USER_ID = 'y41P86RgUjBVekAsVy5u7';

    // Attach a submit event listener to the contact form
    const contactForm = document.getElementById('contact-form');
    contactForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      // Get the values of the name, email, and message fields
      const firstName = document.querySelector('input[name="firstName"]').value.trim();
      const lastName = document.querySelector('input[name="lastName"]').value.trim();
      const email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value.trim();
      const message = document.querySelector('textarea[name="message"]').value.trim();

      // Check that all required fields are filled in
      if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !message) {
        alert('Please fill in all required fields.');
        return;
      }

      // Send the email using EmailJS
      emailjs.send('service_5coma0m', 'template_zvcw48m', {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        email: email,
        message: message
      }, USER_ID)
        .then(function () {
          alert('Your message has been sent.');
          contactForm.reset();
        }, function (error) {
          console.error('Failed to send email:', error);
          alert('An error occurred while sending your message. Please try again later.');
        });
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Unable to send the email succesfully. I don't even how to connect emailjs with my website.

I expect it to be working and cannot find out the issue. It shows 'An error occurred while sending your message. Please try again later.' which is alert when failed to send the mail.

Comment: _Can_ you just call `emailjs.send`?  Their basic installation / setup instructions for this appear to suggest that you would need a call to `emailjs.init` first of all. https://www.emailjs.com/docs/sdk/installation/